# Angular 4: error message should disappear above 6 characters

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm doing a form. If the password field is under 6 characters it should display an error message, and if it's >= 6 characters it shouldn't.

I get the error message with the proper conditions, however the message doesn't dissapear when I type 6 characters in the field.

I would like this error message to dynamically appear and disappear like it does for the 'required' condition.

How do I do it?

Here Is the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input 
    type="text"
    name="password"
    id="password"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="password">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').touched">
    <p class="help-block"
      *ngIf="!signUpForm.get('password').valid">This field is required</p>
    <p class="help-block"
      *ngIf="!signUpForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')">Password must be at list 6 characters</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the ts file:

```
signUpForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
  this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({ 
    'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.minLength(6)]),
    'password':new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  });
}
```

Comment: try this password.hasError('minlength') && !password.hasError('required') and 'password': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],

Comment: remove ! in ngIf condition: *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
<p class="help-block" *ngIf="!signUpForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')">Password must be at list 6 characters</p>
```

means that you show the error when password does NOT have an error. Remove the exclamation mark and change it to:

```
<p class="help-block" *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')">Password must be at list 6 characters</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

for password first add validation in your form initialization

```
  this.signUpForm = new FormGroup( { 
          'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.minLength(6)]),
          'password':new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])
        } );
```

now make some change in your html code

```
<p class="help-block" *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').hasError('minlength') && !signUpForm.get('password').hasError('required')">Password must be at list 6 characters</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out, thank you all for your answers

```
<input 
        type="text"
         name="password"
         id="password"
         class="form-control"
         formControlName="password"
        >
            <div class="help-block"
            *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').touched">
                <p 
                  *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').hasError('required'); else characterNumber">This field is required</p>
                      <ng-template #characterNumber>
                        <p    
                      *ngIf="signUpForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')">Password must be at list 6 characters</p>
                      </ng-template>    
            </div>
```